# The easiest way to set up an encrypted SVN repository?

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav, tortoisesvn, svn

I'm using Subversion and TortoiseSVN under Windows, connecting to a Linux webserver running svnserve. I have basic shell access to the Linux webserver.

I have a non-encrypted link working, i.e. I can connect via TortoiseSVN to:

svn://www.mysite.com/svn/myproject/

However, **I need to convert this to an encrypted link**, e.g.:

svn+ssh://www.mysite.com/svn/myproject/

I can't get it working: any ideas?

p.s. My client will accept nothing less than an encrypted link. Is it necessary? No. Do I need it? Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Would be good to give information on what you tried to make it work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mod_svn & mod_ssl: as easy as configuring an https host.